# Puppeteer PDF generation is not working in the deployed server

Tags: pdf, puppeteer, pdf-generation

I am using puppeteer to generate a pdf and send it as mail. It is working fine in my local Linux environment. But when I try to deploy this to the Linux server it is throwing an error as

```
"message":"Failed to launch the browser process!\n/home/ubuntu/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-1069273/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md\n"
```

Below is my code snippet

```
const generateCertificate = async (data, traineeName, trainingPlanTitle) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        defaultViewport: null,
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setContent(data, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

    const pdf = await page.pdf({
        path: `${traineeName}_${trainingPlanTitle}.pdf`,
        format: 'A4',
        landscape: true,
        margin: 'none',
        printBackground: true,
        scale: 1.3,
    });
    await browser.close();
    return pdf;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Above code working fine for me and generating PDF successfully.

From the error message it seems like libatk-1.0 dependency library missing in linux server.

Try installing the below package and check.

`apt-get install libatk-bridge2.0-0`

Source: [puppeteer dependencies](https://gist.github.com/winuxue/cfef08e2f5fe9dfc16a1d67a4ad38a01)